# Same element not found in jenkins but found when run in eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, jenkins-plugins

Same element not found in jenkins but found when run in eclipse IDE

I have one method which I'm regularly calling in my Test Cases in my Automation Suite.

This method is like below:

```
public void FillCarNo(WebDriver d, String CarNo) throws Throwable
{
    //Actiondriver.waitForElement(d, AppointmentBooking.CarRegistration, 5);
    System.out.println("Before using car registration");
    String no= Actiondriver.getAttribute(d, AppointmentBooking.CarRegistration, "value", "Car Registration Number");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    System.out.println("This"+no+"is");
    System.out.println("After using car registration");
    if(no.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
    {
        System.out.println("Inside car registration if loop");
        Actiondriver.waitForElement(d, AppointmentBooking.CarRegistration, 20);
        Actiondriver.type(d, AppointmentBooking.CarRegistration, CarNo, "Entering Car Number");
        System.out.println("After car registration if loop");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Car Registration Number already filled");
    }
}
```

Now when I run the Test Suite in Eclipse IDE it executes the entire suite successfully but when I run the same suite in Jenkins it's throwing element not found error.

```
Before using car registration
Thisis
After using car registration
Inside car registration if loop
Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*    [@id='carRegistrationNumber']"}
Command duration or timeout: 33 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit:     http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision:      '35ae25b1534ae328c771e0856c93e187490ca824', time: '2016-03-15 10:43:46'
System info: host: 'ROBER-QA', ip: '192.168.137.1', os.name: 'Windows 7',     os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false,     handlesAlerts=true, databaseEnabled=true, version=45.0, platform=WINDOWS,     nativeEvents=false, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true,     locationContextEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true,     javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 4ec86b11-94e9-48eb-97c7-71b676912654
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//*[@id='carRegistrationNumber']}
```

As U can see in the console output the element CarRegistration is working fine in the first place of .getAttribute but inside the if loop it throws Element not found error.

The element is as below:

public static By CarRegistration = By.xpath("//*[@id='carRegistrationNumber']");

Only in Jenkins I'm getting this error and once I get this error the rest of the test cases also fail. Stuck with this issue for almost 2-3 days. Please help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: before looking for that element in loop, make wait for some seconds

Comment: @noor - It doesn't work even after putting Thread.sleep(3000)

Answer (score 2):

The problem that I was having was due to window resizing issue. When I maximized the window by driver.manage().window().maximize(); it always threw error. So I changed the window size and the problem that I was facing didn't exist anymore.

```
Dimension d = new Dimension(1382,744); 
//Resize the current window to the given dimension
driver.manage().window().setSize(d);
```

This is what I set the windows size to and it works completely fine. Don't know why jenkins can't find element in maximized windows but this solves for me.

Comment: Hero of my day!

Answer (score 0):

ID is the most preferable for locating element. As the element has ID you can try ID as below:

```
public static By carRegistration = By.id("carRegistrationNumber");
```

Answer (score 0):

If your Jenkins is hosted from a remote server. Please check once in the server what is the automation flow when test run is invoked.
Can you  please print this method "waitForElement" definition for more clarity on how the wait is working.

Using the same locator 
public static By CarRegistration = By.xpath("//*[@id='carRegistrationNumber']")
try waiting for the element to be clickable in the first place itself.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,60);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(CarRegistration ));
```

Comment: As of now I'm a starter when it comes to Jenkins so entire setup is on my laptop so no point of remote server. waitForElement is actually explicitwait written in a custom way for my framework. CarRegistration is a input text box where in users would enter their car number.

Comment: @Robert : Is the  Custom wait waiting for the element  to be clickable or waiting for element to be visible? . If your using eclipse as an IDE, trying adding a line system.out.println(CarRegistration.isDisplayed()) and put a breakpoint at this point and debug the code. This will ensure whether the id is actually visible on screen or not at that time.

Comment: The problem that I was having was due to window resizing issue. When I maximized the window by driver.manage().window().maximize(); it always threw error. So I changed the window size and the problem that I was facing didn't exist anymore.

    Dimension d = new Dimension(1382,744);
    //Resize the current window to the given dimension
    driver.manage().window().setSize(d);

This is what I set the windows size to.